# Что такое .class?

Tags: java, рефлексия

```
Constructor <User> constructor = User.class.getConstructor(new Class[]{String.class,String.class,String.class});
System.out.println("Constructor  "+constructor);
constructor.newInstance("Hello","From","Reflection");
```

Из данного примера мне понятно что при передачи конструктору создаётся Обьект массива типа `Class`.

Но вводит в заблуждение: `Class.class` после чего позволяется вызывать методы Reflection API. Что означает этот `.class` ?

Я знаю что для доступа к методам надо создать обьект любого класса или если метод статичный то доступ будет произведен через имя класса.. В случае с доступом к Reflection API не понятно это окончание .class, я могу вызвать .class у любого класса или интерфейса или примитива `int.class` как JVM (если так правильно будет сказать) относится к такого рода конструкциям ? Что это и почему оно используется ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Обращение к `.class` после имени типа возвращает объект типа [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html). Этот объект содержит информацию о типе (будь то класс или интерфейс) и используется в тех местах, где нужно передать информацию о типе (рефлексия как один из примеров).

Вызов `.class` *на типе* эквивалентен вызову `getClass()` *на экземпляре типа*. Обычно `.class` используется там, где нужно указать тип, но нет конкретного экземпляра этого типа. Пример для `String`:

```
System.out.println(String.class.getName());
System.out.println("hello".getClass().getName());
```

---

В вашем примере в первой строке вы находите конструктор класса `User`, который принимает три строковых параметра. Для указания типов параметров используется `String.class`.