# Что за тип Class в Java?

Tags: java

Искал в интернете, но не нашел статей, чтобы разобраться что это за тип Class и с чем его едят. Что это за тип такой-то?

Comment: У Шилдта в Полном руководстве этот вопрос неплохо раскрыт.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое .class?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/576365/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-class)

Comment: представьте что вам нужно сделать что-то типа интерпретатора командной строки, который загружает и запускает на исполнение програмы, указанные пользователем. Тогда вам нужет тип для представления загружаемых и исполняемых программ. Программы, исполняемые JVM, представлены на диске класс-файлами, а в оперативной памяти - объектами типа Class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В Java почти все сущности являются объектами, за исключением примитивных типов. У каждого объекта есть класс. Сами классы тоже является объектами, и они принадлежат классу Class.

У класса Class нет публичных конструкторов. Class - это generic тип. Методы Class предназначены для получения информации о классе (объекте типа Class). Например, можно узнать полное имя класса, какие у него аннотации, какие конструкторы и т.п. Эти методы нужны для reflection. С помощью reflection вы можете создавать объекты, которые принадлежат этому классу, и при этом заранее класс объекта вы можете не знать.

Существуют библиотеки, которые позволяют создавать объекты типа Class "на лету", т.е. вы можете создать новый класс прямо во время работы программы и так же можете изменить существующий класс.

Comment: Какие Class имеет конструкторы и методы? Зачем он нужен?

Comment: @bsuart2017 обновил ответ

Comment: @rfq, странный подход у вас. Мне он нужен, чтобы разобраться досконально для себя, так как с этим вещами встречаюсь впервые.

Comment: Почитайте про рефлексию, все станет ясно

Answer (score 1):

`Class` - это класс входящий в пакет `java.lang`. Его едят только в случае, когда необходимо использовать рефлексию.

[Статья](http://devcolibri.com/193).

Вот так можно сделать

```
Class clazz = SecondActivity.class;
```

Помещает класс активности в переменную `clazz`

Comment: нельзя так сделать - "class" нельзя использовать как идентификатор :)

Comment: "`Class` - это класс входящий в пакет `java.lang.reflect`" – а Вы ничего не путаете?

Comment: Уже сам заметил, поторопился

Comment: Название переменной изменили потому что `class` это ключевое слово?

Comment: @СергейГрушин совершенно верно, и без этой правки код был синтаксически неверным ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯